# cakephp find all condition AND OR

Tags: cakephp, find, nested, conditional-statements

Below is my condition:

```
'OR' =>
    array(
        'AND' => array(
            array('EventCompetitor.is_black' => 1),
            array('EventCompetitor.is_adult' => 1)
        ),
        'AND' => array(
            array('EventCompetitor.is_black' => 0),
            array('EventCompetitor.is_adult' => 0)
        ),
    ),
```

When I debug my query, it comes something like this, which is wrong:

```
AND ((`EventCompetitor`.`is_black` = 0) AND (`EventCompetitor`.`is_adult` = 0)) AND
```

Now, that's not what I want, I want it something like this:

```
((`EventCompetitor`.`is_black` = 1) AND (`EventCompetitor`.`is_adult` = 1)) OR ((`EventCompetitor`.`is_black` = 0) AND (`EventCompetitor`.`is_adult` = 0))
```

Any idea, how can I achieve it?

Thanks !

Answer (score 16, accepted):

your subkeys in your "OR" keyed array are the same name, with the second key effectively overwriting the first.  you need to encapsulate those "AND" conditions in their own arrays, to prevent the key collision.

eg. instead of:

```
'OR' =>
        array(
               'AND' => array(
                              array('EventCompetitor.is_black' => 1),
                              array('EventCompetitor.is_adult' => 1)
                        ),
               'AND' => array(
                              array('EventCompetitor.is_black' => 0),
                              array('EventCompetitor.is_adult' => 0)
                        ),
             ),
```

do:

```
'OR' =>
        array(
               array('AND' => array(
                              array('EventCompetitor.is_black' => 1),
                              array('EventCompetitor.is_adult' => 1)
                        )),
               array('AND' => array(
                              array('EventCompetitor.is_black' => 0),
                              array('EventCompetitor.is_adult' => 0)
                        )),
             ),
```

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tested it, but I think you need the following:

```
'OR' =>
    array(
        array(
            array('EventCompetitor.is_black' => 1),
            array('EventCompetitor.is_adult' => 1)
        ),
        array(
            array('EventCompetitor.is_black' => 0),
            array('EventCompetitor.is_adult' => 0)
        )
    )
```

`AND` is implied between conditions, you only have to define `OR`  groups

Answer (score 0):

I think you need an extra array() in there, im not sure but its worth a try:

```
'OR' =>
    array(
        array(
            'AND' => array(
                array('EventCompetitor.is_black' => 1),
                array('EventCompetitor.is_adult' => 1)
            )
        ),
        array(
            'AND' => array(
                array('EventCompetitor.is_black' => 0),
                array('EventCompetitor.is_adult' => 0)
            )
        )
    ),
```