# CakePHP query with AND OR

Tags: php, cakephp

I have the following query which should be finding:

- A row where the user_id matches userId and friend_id matches friendId
- OR a row where the user_id matches friendId and friend_id matches userId
- AND both also have status of 1

My code is:

```
public function isFriend($userId, $friendId)
{
    return $search = $this->Friend->find('first', array(
            'conditions'=>array(
                'OR' => array(
                    'AND'=>array(
                        'Friend.user_id'=>$userId,
                        'Friend.friend_id'=>$friendId
                    ),
                    'AND'=>array(
                        'Friend.user_id'=>$friendId,
                        'Friend.friend_id'=>$userId
                    )
                ),
                'AND' => array(
                    'Friend.status'=>1
                )
            )
        )
    );
}
```

However it's not working... I've looked around and seems it's to do with getting the arrays correctly when dealing with the two AND calls, but I don't get it. Can anyone help me out?

Thanks

Comment: you should know that you cannot use an array key twice in the same array.

Comment: I don't know. Hence the question. I looked here for help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649185/cakephp-find-all-condition-and-or and that's how I put my code together.

Comment: on that page it's exactly my solution, you used the code which Jason titled with "eg. instead of". You have to use the code block below that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the same array key twice as mark said, so you have to encapsulate the ANDs in separate arrays

```
'OR' => 
array(
    array('AND'=>array(
            'Friend.user_id'=>$userId,
            'Friend.friend_id'=>$friendId
        )
    ),
    array('AND'=>array(
            'Friend.user_id'=>$friendId,
            'Friend.friend_id'=>$userId
        )
    )
),
'AND' => array(
    'Friend.status'=>1
)
```

Comment: Thanks. Too many arrays and it was confusing hell outta me ;)